# codeigniter anchor set a ID

Tags: codeigniter

how can i put a ID on this

```
<?php echo anchor('profil', 'Profil'); ?>
```

i wanna echo a username ID to it like

```
<a href="profil.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">Profile</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo anchor('profil.php?id='.$id, 'My News');
```

but you'd better use the CodeIgniter router and place the id as parameter, e.g:

```
echo anchor('profil/'.$id, 'My News');
```

this will output a link like:

```
http://www.site.com/profil/233
```

Comment: +1, infinity is correct, but this will (possibly) cause errors - OP take note. CI will attempt to look for a method called "233" (in this example), which of course will be invalid unless you have routing set up to handle this request. you may mean: `profil/view/$id` or similar.